# KeyError: 'Key x not found.'

Tags: python, keyerror, mcedit

I have this code from a MCEDit filter I was editing:

```
def getCommand(level, box):
    for x in xrange(box.minx,box.maxx):
        for y in xrange(box.miny,box.maxy):
            for z in xrange(box.minz,box.maxz):
                t = level.tileEntityAt(x, y, z)
                                if t and t["id"].value == "Control":
                                        if "id" in t: del t["id"]
                                        if "x" in t: del t["x"]
                                        if "y" in t: del t["y"]
                                        if "z" in t: del t["z"]
                                        return (t, x, y, z)
        return (None, None, None, None)
```

And I get this error:

`'KeyError: 'Key x not found.'`

Please help!

EDIT:

Fixed, thanks @Texelelf:

```
def getCommand(level, box):
for x in xrange(box.minx,box.maxx):
    for y in xrange(box.miny,box.maxy):
        for z in xrange(box.minz,box.maxz):
            t = deepcopy(level.tileEntityAt(x,y,z))
            if t and t["id"].value == "Control":
                if "id" in t: del t["id"]
                if "x" in t: del t["x"]
                if "y" in t: del t["y"]
                if "z" in t: del t["z"]
                return (t, x, y, z)
    return (None, None, None, None)
```

Comment: What line is the error? I assume it is at `if "x" in t: del t["x"]`. Can you print what `level.tileEntityAt(x, y, z)` does?

Comment: It is actually at line: t = level.tileEntityAt(x, y, z), I don't really know if MCEdit can print what "level.tileEntityAt(x, y, z)"does, sorry.

Comment: If you have a solution you should post it as an answer and mark it accepted. It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: @ Mike W Ok, did that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getCommand(level, box):
for x in xrange(box.minx,box.maxx):
    for y in xrange(box.miny,box.maxy):
        for z in xrange(box.minz,box.maxz):
            t = deepcopy(level.tileEntityAt(x,y,z))
            if t and t["id"].value == "Control":
                if "id" in t: del t["id"]
                if "x" in t: del t["x"]
                if "y" in t: del t["y"]
                if "z" in t: del t["z"]
                return (t, x, y, z)
    return (None, None, None, None)
```

Got the answer, thanks to @Texelelf on Twitter

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function:

```
def getCommand(level, box):
    for x in xrange(box.minx,box.maxx):
        for y in xrange(box.miny,box.maxy):
            for z in xrange(box.minz,box.maxz):
                t = level.tileEntityAt(x, y, z)
                                if t and t["id"].value == "Control":
                                        if "id" in t: del t["id"]
                                        if "x" in t: del t["x"]
                                        if "y" in t: del t["y"]
                                        if "z" in t: del t["z"]
                                        return (t, x, y, z)
        return (None, None, None, None)
```

In the second line of your code, you assign `x` in a `for` loop. You then proceed to call `t = level.tileEntityat(x, y, z)`, which means you are looking for the value of `x`, as defined in your second line. Instead, surround your `x`, `y`, and `z` in quotations, to make them strings. I am not completely sure this is what you want because I don't know what is in `level.tileEntityAt(x, y, z)`, but I'm making my best guess.

Edited code:

```
def getCommand(level, box):
    for x in xrange(box.minx,box.maxx):
        for y in xrange(box.miny,box.maxy):
            for z in xrange(box.minz,box.maxz):
                t = level.tileEntityAt("x", "y", "z")
                    if t and t["id"].value == "Control":
                        if "id" in t: del t["id"]
                        if "x" in t: del t["x"]
                        if "y" in t: del t["y"]
                        if "z" in t: del t["z"]
                        return (t, x, y, z)
        return (None, None, None, None)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work: the loop variables `x`, `y` and `z` would then not be used.

Comment: Well now I get a indentation error: `    if t and t["id"].value == "Control":
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: That's because your original indenting was off. Check my edited code.

Comment: Don't you think the OP would need the `x, y, z` parameters as integers? (dunno, maybe not)

Comment: It wasn't very clear in the question, downvoter, why the downvote?